# What currencies does Sage Pay Pi support?

Tags: rest, currency, opayo

Sage Pay Pi - the RESTful Sage Pay gateway - uses [ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) currency codes. What is not clear to me from the documentation is what the full range of supported currencies are.

Does the gateway support ALL ISO 4217 currencies, so long as the attached merchant account supports it? Or can Sage Pay only deal with a subset of these currencies regardless of what the merchant account is capable of?

I believe the Sage Pay Pi gateway is a wrapper around the Sage Pay Direct gateway, so knowing what currencies that gateway is capable of supporting would be sufficient.

---

The reason for asking is for deciding how currencies will be supported and validated in a PHP package for this gateway. A follow-on question would be recommendations for a composer package that provides support for currency value objects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only Sage Pay can authoritatively answer this question.

Comment: The trouble is, the Sage Pay forum where questions like this used to be asked, is now a page that sends people *here* for all support questions. My assumption is that if Sage Pay are making this section of SO their official developer support channel, then they will be here to answer such questions. Then the answers will be here for other people to read. Otherwise I would be phoning them up and keeping the answer to myself.

Comment: @Jason: The point is that questions like these are off-topic for SO, regardless of if they're answered by the product's team. If Microsoft were to come in here answering questions about crashing systems, those questions would still be off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sage Pay's gateway supports around 160 currencies.

You are right in assuming that these need to be supported by the acquirer.

There is also a limitation on card type eg: JCB just supports EUR,GBP,JPY,USD as opposed to AMEX which supports AUD, CAD, CHF, CYP, DKK, EUR, GBP, HKD, INR, JPY, MTL, NOK, NZD, RUB, SEK, SGD, THB, TRY, USD, ZAR and so on with minor variations between card types.

I would start by contacting your acquirer, and find out what currencies they support.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. This is actually for a composer package I've written, so I'm not so concerned about what my own account supports. This is enough for me to know I need to simply support any currency in the package. I would use the ISO lists to determine where the decimal point goes, and how many digits to zero-pad the amount, since the number format is important for Sage Pay (decimal in some APIs, and integer in the Pi API).

Comment: @Rik, I see you're an SagePay employee.  You'll want to have a look at this [Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340887/sage-pay-support-directs-to-stack-overflow) about SagePay linking to SO for support questions. There are several links in there that have guidelines on how a company _can_ link to SO for their customers.

Comment: @Rik, we're waiting for a response on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340887/sage-pay-support-directs-to-stack-overflow